# aws cli tool set up - unable to connect ec2 and retrieve instance information

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am trying to use `aws configure` to set up the cli tool

```
aws configure --profile work
AWS Access Key ID [None]: ABCD
AWS Secret Access Key [None]: 123456
Default region name [None]: 
Default output format [None]:
```

It creates one file:

```
cat ~/.aws/config 
[profile work]
aws_access_key_id = ABCD
aws_secret_access_key = 123456
```

The I set the default profile to `work` in bash shell

```
export AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=work
```

And executes `aws  ec2 describe-instances`

However it seems to hang. After waiting for 5 minutes I Ctrl-C the command. I have no trouble getting the instance information form the ec2 console.

What has gone wrong? I noticed there is some documentation that says the SDK and CLI are expecting different configuration files format. Is it a factor?

Here is the stacktrace from the ctrl-c

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/antkong/aws/aws-ve/bin/aws", line 23, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/antkong/aws/aws-ve/bin/aws", line 19, in main
    return awscli.clidriver.main()
  File "/Users/antkong/aws/aws-ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 49, in main
    return driver.main()
  File "/Users/antkong/aws/aws-ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 195, in main
    return command_table[parsed_args.command](remaining, parsed_args)
  File "/Users/antkong/aws/aws-ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 343, in __call__
    return command_table[parsed_args.operation](remaining, parsed_globals)
  File "/Users/antkong/aws/aws-ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 450, in __call__
    self._operation_object, call_parameters, parsed_globals)
  File "/Users/antkong/aws/aws-ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 553, in invoke
    parsed_globals)
  File "/Users/antkong/aws/aws-ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 566, in _display_response
    formatter(operation, response)
  File "/Users/antkong/aws/aws-ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/formatter.py", line 224, in __call__
    for _, page in response:
  File "/Users/antkong/aws/aws-ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/paginate.py", line 156, in __iter__
    **current_kwargs)
  File "/Users/antkong/aws/aws-ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/operation.py", line 68, in call
    response = endpoint.make_request(self, params)
  File "/Users/antkong/aws/aws-ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 69, in make_request
    return self._send_request(prepared_request, operation)
  File "/Users/antkong/aws/aws-ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 123, in _send_request
    attempts)
  File "/Users/antkong/aws/aws-ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 132, in _get_response
    proxies=self.proxies, timeout=self.timeout)
  File "/Users/antkong/aws/aws-ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/sessions.py", line 464, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/antkong/aws/aws-ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/adapters.py", line 321, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/Users/antkong/aws/aws-ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 471, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/Users/antkong/aws/aws-ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 285, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 995, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/Users/antkong/aws/aws-ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/awsrequest.py", line 116, in _send_request
    self, method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1029, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 991, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/Users/antkong/aws/aws-ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/awsrequest.py", line 130, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Users/antkong/aws/aws-ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/awsrequest.py", line 203, in send
    return HTTPConnection.send(self, str)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 806, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/antkong/aws/aws-ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 73, in connect
    timeout=self.timeout,
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 562, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

**EDIT**

When I turn on the debug flag, I got these information:

```
2014-10-02 13:16:04,019 - MainThread - botocore.retryhandler - DEBUG - retry needed, retryable exception caught: (<botocore.awsrequest.AWSHTTPSConnection instance at 0x1091c1cf8>, 'Connection to ec2.us-west-2a.amazonaws.com timed out. (connect timeout=60)')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/antkong/aws/aws-ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 262, in _should_retry
    return self._checker(attempt_number, response, caught_exception)
  File "/Users/antkong/aws/aws-ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 310, in __call__
    caught_exception)
  File "/Users/antkong/aws/aws-ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 219, in __call__
    return self._check_caught_exception(attempt_number, caught_exception)
  File "/Users/antkong/aws/aws-ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 352, in _check_caught_exception
    raise caught_exception
Timeout: (<botocore.awsrequest.AWSHTTPSConnection instance at 0x1091c1cf8>, 'Connection to ec2.us-west-2a.amazonaws.com timed out. (connect timeout=60)')
2014-10-02 13:16:04,019 - MainThread - botocore.retryhandler - DEBUG - Retry needed, action of: 2.20577344724
2014-10-02 13:16:04,019 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Response received to retry, sleeping for 2.20577344724 seconds
2014-10-02 13:16:06,225 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Sending http request: <PreparedRequest [POST]>
2014-10-02 13:16:06,226 - MainThread - botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool - INFO - Starting new HTTPS connection (4): ec2.us-west-2a.amazonaws.com
```

Apparently I can ping the url: ec2.us-west-2a.amazonaws.com

So why the timeout?

Comment: Try aws ec2 describe-instances --profile work ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it does not work.

Comment: Ping will only show you that you can resolve DNS and send and recive ICMP traffic to that host. AWS CLI tools will issue HTTPs request. To simulate that you need to use a telnet command : 'telnet ec2.us-west-2a.amazonaws.com 443'